# Get all request data from port 80 with NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am creating **cross platform tracking system** with **NodeJS** script, that will store all **HTTP requests** into MySQL table along with IPv4/MAC/URL columns.

(We will install **NodeJS** script to all computers for which I want to track HTTP requests, users will browse websites and we want to track that websites requests.)

My problem is that I've created a server that will listen to port 3000, but I'm not able to get requests coming from other ports like 80 where all browser requests are going.

**Please Note:** For security reasons I have to run node js script to port 3000 instead of port 80

**Please Note:** With node logging libraries, I am able to get HTTP requests which I'm sending to localhost:3000 port but not other requests that are coming through port 80 (Which are users browsers HTTP requests).

Here is the code I've developed.

```
// HTTP Module
var http = require('http');

// OS Utility Module
var os = require('os-utils');

// Native OS object
var osNative = require('os');

// MySQL Connection Setup
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Create server
var server = http.createServer(function() {});

// Set server to listen on PORT 5656
server.listen(3000);

// Acknowledge that server is listening
console.log("Server is listening");

// Now, how to get this script to receive all HTTP requests? Stuck here.
```

Comment: You can't do this with normal networking code. By that I mean you can't use sockets. What you want instead is a socket tap which is usually a device driver (kernel code). Google wireshark or tcpdump and find out what libraries they're using. I used to write software for routers and firewalls and we used a library called libpcap (for PacketCAPture) which is what tcpdump uses.

Comment: Thank you so much for your pointers to libpcap. I found Node implementation for this library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap Let me check If I can parse HTTP requests from that.